# Does exist a linux service for watching/checking (and restarting, i.e. for a segfault) running daemons?

Tags: linux, daemon, monit, watchdog

I'm searching for a linux service that watches/checks every n seconds a list of running processes/daemons for detecting (and noticing+restarting the process) any issues (like a segmentation fault in nginx).

Is there any?

Comment: Monit is a common choice for this. However, it is also [very well-documented here.](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/monit?sort=votes&pagesize=50). Try checking the existing Monit questions to see if any fit your use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). It can do more than just monitoring processes though which shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are several.  They're called `watchdogs`

DJB's daemontools does this (but it's icky. I'm not even giving you a link.)

There are also various examples of watchdog scripts people have written ([this one is pretty decent](http://blog.eracc.com/2010/05/08/linux-monitor-a-service-with-a-watchdog-script/)) - usually it's a shell script that reads a PID file, checks to see if the corresponding PID is alive, and either notifies you or restarts the affected service if it's not.
They're typically run out of `cron` jobs every minute/5 minutes/ etc. - tighter granularity than that is almost never necessary in the real world.

If you have a proper monitoring system in place you can often hook your monitoring system so alerts go to a handler script that tries to restart services that are down (but beware the negative impact of false alarms here - restarting your webserver when you don't need to could cause more harm than good).

Comment: I quite like upstart.

Comment: Upstart is supposed to be pretty good, and comes with modern Ubuntu (and Debian?) which is a bonus. I haven't worked with it much personally.